# How to remove Up Down arrow keys from asp:textbox texmode:date?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, date, textbox

How to remove Up Down arrow keys from `asp:textbox texmode:date`? I have  textbox with textmode date and I just want the calender arrow ?? how can I achieve this? in picture how can I disable the marked area controls?? [image]

```
<asp:TextBox Width="95%" ID="tourEndDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date"  onkeypress="return false" onKeyDown="return false"></asp:TextBox></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
  <Style>
    input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
         display: none;
         }
    </style>
```

[image]

Or you can use datepicker. Just

Download `AjaxControlToolkit.dll` from web, add it to bin folder, then Add reference and then add

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

to your aspx page. Style Part

```
<style type="text/css">
.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_container   {
background-color: #DEF1F4;
border:solid 1px #77D5F7;
}

.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_header  {
background-color: #ffffff;
margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_title,
.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_next,
.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_prev    {
color: #004080;
padding-top: 3px;
}

.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_body    {
background-color: #ffffff;
border: solid 1px #77D5F7;
}

.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_dayname {
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
margin-bottom: 4px;
margin-top: 2px;
color: #004080;
}
</style>
```

Your TextBox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="ceFromDate" CssClass= " cal_Theme1" TargetControlID="txtDate" Format="dd-MMM-yyyy" runat="server"/>
```

[image]

It will appear like this.

Comment: nd how to remove that cross?

Comment: Why don't you use datepicker ?

Comment: to restrict past dates check the link http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/11/disable-past-dates-in-jquery-datepicker.html